# Django template form not posting

Tags: python, html, django, post, django-forms

I'm doing an app and for some strange reason, I am not able to store the values of the form to the database. 
The problem is that the data are not sent via POST, therefore my view doesn't collect them. What would be the reason for that?
My (simplified) Template code:

```
{% block content %}
<form action = "{%url 'bodySettings' %}" method = "POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <input type = "submit" value = "Save"/>
</form>

{% endblock content %}
```

And my django view:

```
@login_required
@csrf_protect
def bodysettings(request):

    properties_Form = BodyPropertiesForm()


    if request.method == 'POST':
        print ("test")
        if properties_Form.is_valid():

            properties = properties_Form.save(commit = False)
            properties.user = request.user
            properties.save()

            return HttpResponseRedirect('/home/')

    args = {}
    args.update(csrf(request))
    args['request'] = request
    args['form'] = properties_Form

    return render_to_response('stats_test.html',args)
```

And my forms.py:

```
    from django import forms
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User
    from models import Body

    class BodyPropertiesForm(forms.ModelForm):
    MALE = 'M'
    FEMALE = 'F'
    GENDER_CHOICE = (
    (MALE, 'male'),
    (FEMALE, 'female'),
    )

gender      = forms.ChoiceField(choices = GENDER_CHOICE, required = True, 
    help_text = "Select your gender")
height      = forms.IntegerField(required = True, help_text = "Enter your height")
weight      = forms.IntegerField(required = True, help_text = "Enter your body weight" )
neck        = forms.IntegerField(required = True, help_text = "Enter your neck size")
shoulders   = forms.IntegerField(required = True, help_text = "Enter your width")
chest       = forms.IntegerField(required = True, help_text = "Enter your chest size")
arm         = forms.IntegerField(required = True, help_text = "Enter your arm size")
wrist       = forms.IntegerField(required = True, help_text = "Enter your wrist size")
hips        = forms.IntegerField(required = True, help_text = "Enter your waist size ")
waist       = forms.IntegerField(required = True, help_text = "Enter your hips size")
thigh       = forms.IntegerField(required = True, help_text = "Enter your thigh size")
calf        = forms.IntegerField(required = True, help_text = "Enter your calf size")

class Meta:
    model = Body
    fields = ('gender','height','weight','neck','shoulders','chest','arm','wrist',
        'waist','hips','thigh','calf')
    exclude = ('user',)
```

Comment: Paste your `forms.py` here,I think there is no name defined for `input` field.

Answer (score 2):

You're not passing your POST values to the form.

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    properties_Form = BodyPropertiesForm(request.POST)
```

Comment: In my case when I press the submit input the POST dict is empty (the method is supposedly GET). Therefore this IF statement is false.

Comment: Then you're not showing us your real template, because you clearly set method=POST there.

Comment: That's what bothers me. The GET dict however gets filled up with the data from the form fields.

Answer (score 0):

You can see in terminal whether it is `post` or `get` request.Here data will be `post` i think.The problem which `query dict` is empty is because,

```
class NameForm(forms.Form):
    your_name = forms.CharField(label='myfieldname', max_length=100)
```

So `label` should be there in form.This can be fetch in `view` as `request.POST['myfieldname']`.Also you have to use

```
properties_Form = BodyPropertiesForm(request.POST)
```

Hope this helps